# How to allow array to accept only unique indices of listboxes and throw an exception if item selected is same as any previous selection (c#)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm still fairly new to C# programming language. I have to create a airplane reservation program in which user will input the name and select the item (seat number) from each of two listboxes. First listbox include items namely A,B,C,D,E & second list box include items 1,2,3. There are total 15 seats-A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,E1,E2,E3,E4,E5. Program demands each seat to be selected once.If one seat is selected more than one time, message should pop up which says- this seat is already chosen.When I click on Book button -The passenger name and seat number should be printed in richtextbox1(one below "Show all" button).

I have coded an array to accept the listbox items to print the items in richtextbox along with passenger name. 
Everything is working fine except with code part(part which I have made comment) where I have coded if else inside for loop to check array elements with same values and message if condition is satisfied.

Here's my code:

```
    private void book_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[,] newarray = new string[5, 3];


        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name is required");
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 && listBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Seat Number is required");

        }
        else if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || listBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Seat Number is required");
        }
        else
        {                
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {

                    newarray[i, j] = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem) + listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem);
                    listBox1.ClearSelected();
                    listBox2.ClearSelected();
                    richTextBox1.Text += "" + textBox1.Text + "  " + newarray[i, j] + "";
                    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;

                }
            }
            richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
       /*for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
          {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                if (newarray[i, 0] == newarray[j, 1])
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This seat is already chosen");
                }
                if (newarray[i, 1]==newarray[j,2])
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("This seat is already chosen"); 
                }

            }
          }/*
        }
    }
```

It's not working and now every time I click on book button- it shows popup message saying -this seat is already chosen.I don't know where's the problem. This is my own approach so I'm not sure where I'm doing wrong.I would appreciate any help.

Here's the link the GUI- If you see the users John and Jon have been assigned same seat(D3) number which should not be the case.

[image]

Comment: My project specifically ask to use array and loop to generate the output.

Comment: I have commented out the code because it does not work.

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting here. You assign a value like "D3" to the first element of `newarray` and print the "booking event" to the bottom textbox without any checks. The commented code afterwards doesn't make any sense (it would always show the message because all elements of `newarray` would be empty except the first one).

Comment: I'm expecting the message to popup when I select the item from list box which is already selected and assigned to array element.

Comment: I know the commented code does not work but what's wrong with the rest? How can I improve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the booking state on the class level, not on the method level because it would be empty after each click on the "Book" button.

You should also check the conditions before you print booking event info.

So the code should look like this:

```cs
public class Test
{
    private bool[,] bookingState = new bool[5,3];

    private void book_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name is required");
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 && listBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Seat Number is required");

        }
        else if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || listBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Seat Number is required");
        }

        // Now checking if the seat is booked
        string rowLetter = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        // Insert checks for proper number format here
        int displayedRowSeatNumber = int.Parse(listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem));
        // arrays are 0-based in C# so seat #1 would be at position 0.
        int rowSeatNumber = displayedRowSeatNumber - 1;


        // here you convert your row letter to row number for the booking array check
        // I'll use 1 for the example which is equivalent to B row
        int rowNumber = 1;

        if (bookingState[rowNumber, rowSeatNumber]) {
            MessageBox.Show("Seat has been booked!");
        }
        else {
            bookingState[rowNumber, rowSeatNumber] = true;
            // You can use string interpolation here as well
            richTextBox1.Text += textBox1.Text
                + " "
                + listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem) 
                + listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem)
                + "/n";
        }
    }
}
```

If you use a string array instead of a bool array you can save the name of the client there and use it to show who exactly booked the flight.

**UPD**: updated the answer with value preparation before checking.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I don't understand What's the rowNumber for? What's the condition in if statement suppose to do?. Kindly explain.

Comment: you have a table(which is a 2-dimensional array) of booking marks. Each cell is a seat with a row number and a seat number. Displayed row numbers are A,B,C etc. but we encode them with numbers to match them against array indices. The condition checks if the cell for the selected seat has the booking mark set.